# Mention bot for prefix discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey guys im making a discord bot with discord.py rewrite and i have a command when mention the bot it will send you the prefix

[But i have this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KfTJ.png)

i dont want the bot to send the prefix when there's others text in the message

This is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Support(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, message):
    if self.client.user.mentioned_in(message):
      mention = discord.Embed(
        title = "The prefix is `,help`",
        colour = 0xeeffee
      )
      await message.channel.send(embed = mention)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Support(client))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are two ideas how it could work :)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Support(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, message):
    if self.client.user.mentioned_in(message):
      checkMessage = message.content.split("@")
      if checkMessage[0] == "@":
        mention = discord.Embed(
          title = "The prefix is `,help`",
          colour = 0xeeffee
        )
      await message.channel.send(embed = mention)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Support(client))
```

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Support(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, message):
    if self.client.user.mentioned_in(message):
      if message.content.startswith("@"):
        mention = discord.Embed(
          title = "The prefix is `,help`",
          colour = 0xeeffee
        )
      await message.channel.send(embed = mention)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Support(client))
```

Comment: Oh btw you have to use `message.content` because message is a class

Comment: Yep i already did and thanks